# Easy method to subtract all the columns from one reference column .Sum and square it and store it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Basically I am subtracting all the columns with respect to reference column and then summing and squaring the value. There is one column named `ReferenceSpeed` and columns `speed1,speed2,speed3.....` I am just subtracting all the speeds (1, 2, 3....) with respect to the `ReferenceSpeed` by using loops go through each row and make this update.
And then sum and square it.

The data in my Excel file is structured like this:

```
ReferenceSpeed  speed1 speed2 speed3 .... speedn
      63           78     56     87 ..........
      54           56     45     98
       .            .      .      .
       .            .      .       .
       .            .      .       .
```

I need to easy method to do this. Maybe a small function .

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

speedlist=['ReferenceSpeed','speed1','speed2','speed3','speed4','speed5','speed6','speed7','speed8','speed9','speed10']

df = pd.read_csv('F:\\Python\\projects\\testdrivingcycles.csv',usecols=['position','ReferenceSpeed','speed1','speed2','speed3','speed4','speed5','speed6','speed7','speed8','speed9','speed10' ]) 

dict1={'ReferenceSpeed':0 ,'speed1':0 , 'speed2':0 ,'speed3':0 , 'speed4':0 ,'speed5':0 ,'speed6':0 , 'speed7':0 ,'speed8':0 ,'speed9':0 ,'speed10':0} 

for speed in speedlist: #to itrrate through col
    for ind in df.index: # to itrrate through rows and selects the data according to the index values.
        
        dict1[speed] = dict1[speed] + (df['ReferenceSpeed'][ind]-df[speed][ind]) # to subtract the difference

    dict1[speed] = dict1[speed] * dict1[speed] # to calculate square

print(dict1)
```

my OUTPUT-
{'ReferenceSpeed': 0, 'speed1': 7056, 'speed2': 6400, 'speed3': 7225, 'speed4': 6561, 'speed5': 6241, 'speed6': 7056, 'speed7': 8281, 'speed8': 10201, 'speed9': 10609, 'speed10': 11025} –

Comment: can you share some examples of the data please? If you already have speed1 in the original data, are you trying to overwrite it with another value? Are you trying to use loops to go through each row and make this update? In Pandas, you dont have to iterate through each row separately. Please share example of Source Data and Expected Output

Comment: Basically the data is all positive numbers from 60-100. and their is one column named ReferenceSpeed and columns named speed1,speed2,speed3..... i am just subtracted all the speeds(1,2,3....) with respect to the ReferenceSpeed by using loops go through each row and make this update. and then sum and square it . so i need a simple function to do this. can you help me.

Comment: OUTPUT-                                                                                                                                       {'ReferenceSpeed': 0, 'speed1': 7056, 'speed2': 6400, 'speed3': 7225, 'speed4': 6561, 'speed5': 6241, 'speed6': 7056, 'speed7': 8281, 'speed8': 10201, 'speed9': 10609, 'speed10': 11025}

Comment: @2GI18ME074OMKAR_GURAV I have posted a solution that should work for you. But I couldn't test since you didn't provide any sample data. Try it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I see your input data. What is your output data? I don't understand the `my OUTPUT - {....` section. Can you create a list of `ReferenceSpeed`, `speed1`, `speed2`, `speed3`  and give us input and output. It will help us understand the problem more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do that all in loops, that will be slow. You are already using `pandas` and `numpy`, so take the advantage of **vectorized** operations they provide.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('F:\\Python\\projects\\testdrivingcycles.csv',usecols=['position','ReferenceSpeed','speed1','speed2','speed3','speed4','speed5','speed6','speed7','speed8','speed9','speed10' ]) 

dict1 = np.square(df.loc[:,'ReferenceSpeed':].subtract(df.ReferenceSpeed, axis=0).sum()).to_dict()

print(dict1)
```